# How do I wait for the callback passed to a Cypress custom command to finish before proceeding the test?

Tags: cypress

I have this code:

```js
cy.visit(Cypress.env('frontendUrl'))
  .pathShould('be', '/login')
  .log('Reached')
```

My custom command `pathShould` looks like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('pathShould', (chain, path) => {
  cy.location('pathname', { timeout: 20000 }).should(chain, path);
});
```

In some cases the `should` assertion is executed, in others it isn't, like here:

[image]

How do I ensure that the callback of my custom command is executed completely before continuing the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that there is not an assertion named `be`.

`cy.should('be', '')` won't do anything - it's [not a valid assertion](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html). You're probably looking for `cy.should('eq'...)`

This works for me:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('pathShould', (chain, path) => {
  return cy.location('pathname', { timeout: 20000 }).should(chain, path);
});

it('', () => {
  cy.visit('http://example.com')
  .pathShould('eq', '/')
  .log('Reached')
})
```

[image: passing test screenshot]

Comment: @303 updated my answer after doing some debugging :)

Comment: @303 There's also an open issue to make using non-existent assertions like `be` result in an error: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/883

Comment: Thank you so much for catching this!

Answer (score 2):

On a side note: it is probably an overkill to use a custom command like this, as you don't really gain anything by wrapping a one liner. Take a look at: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Best-Practices